# How can i change applicationbar item icon on a list event?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Im using a `ApplicationBarIconButton` to enable and disable if the user can edit a list (`Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit`'s `MultiselectList`).

When the user clicks the `ApplicationBarIconButton` the icon changes from select icon to delete icon.

But if the status of the list changes `IsSelectionEnabled` to false again (the user unchecked the item) I can't seem to get a hold of the `ApplicationBarIconButton`... its null!

Here is the list's event for if the editing "mode" (`IsSelectionEnabled`) has changed:

```
private void ListOfFriends_IsSelectionEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var list = sender as MultiselectList;

            if( list.IsSelectionEnabled )
                EditMenuButton.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/ApplicationBar/Select.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

Here it throws telling `EditMenuButton` is null :-(

How can i fix this? Isnt it all running in UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).IconUri = new Uri("SplashScreenImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
```